# Duplicate Columns

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I have a report on RS. One of the cells have the date. In my computer the date is dd/mm/yyyy. On the server where it is going to be run it's mm/dd/yyyy.

Which expression can I use to make it dd/mm/yyyy on the side of the server?

Thanks,

Comment: Impossible to answer without more information. In general though keep dates as date variables so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: You want the report to use the culture of the server of you want to force the culture to `dd/mm/yyyy`?

Comment: To force it as the culture takes mm/dd/yyyy and it should be dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

```
=Format(<date field>, "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

See also:

Format Function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59bz1f0h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Custom Date and Time Formats: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That is really nice, I have the following:

=IIF(Parameters!Uperiodo.Value = "Día",(Format(Parameters!Desde.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")),(Format(Parameters!Desde.Value, "mm/yyyy")))

The problem is, it's returning dd/mm/yyyy and not the formated date.

Comment: Is the parameter "Desde" definitely a Date/Time parameter, and not Text? Also note that the capitalisation of the format string matters: mm = minutes, MM = months

Comment: It is text, so I assume I need to parse it to date.
Is it possible to use DateTime.parse inside an expression of RS? Inside a cell of a table on the report?

Thanks!

Comment: If the parameter is Text then you don't actually have any date data to convert or format. Instead you should look at string manipulation functions (e.g. Left, Substring) to parse and re-format the parameter text to look the way you want it.